# Test a method which calls another method from the viewChild using Jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have this method that validates the component and it's calling out to this another component which is it's `ViewChild`. I am using the component using `this.ViewChildComponent.someMethod();` in the component which I am trying to test. I tried to use the `spyOn(viewChildComponent, 'someMethod').and.returnValue(true)`.
But it says the `this.ViewChildComponent.someMethod() is undefined`. I have all the dependencies such as services for the `ViewChildComponent` on the providers. I even went a step forward and made the call that the `viewChildComponent` makes to its service to decide `someMethod();`

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: To be concise I wanna know how to fulfill dependency for ViewChild

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have for example

```
class TestedComponent() {
     @ViewChild('ChildComp') public variableChildComponent: ChildComp;
}
```

In testing spec file declare child component and tested component:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
     declarations: [ TestedComponent, ChildComp]
  })
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestedComponent);
  comp = fixture.componentInstance;
  spyOn(comp.variableChildComponent, 'someMethod').and.returnValue(true);
});
```

This should work.

Comment: Not a good solution, you are creating a hard dependency on ChildComp. If it stops working your tests will fail, if it changes behaviour, the tests may fail. Better approach is to create child component stub as described in official Angular documentation https://angular.io/guide/testing#nested-component-tests or use ng-mocks library for mocking child components https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-mocks

Comment: An updated link to the Angular2+ documentation for nested component tests: https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#nested-component-tests

Answer (score 6):

@DanielDrozzel answer may solve your problem, but essentially it is flawed and not a good practice. I would like to offer an alternative.
In Daniel's answer, when you use `declarations: [ TestedComponent, ChildComp]` you create a tight coupling in your unit tests between `TestedComponent` and `ChildComp`. If the child component stops working your tests will fail, if it changes behaviour, the tests may fail.

It's not always a bad thing, but it can sometimes bite you. 
It's better to use Component Stubs as mentioned in official Angular Docs
https://angular.io/guide/testing#nested-component-tests or a very useful [ng-mocks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-mocks) library. The third option mentioned in the Angular docks above is `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` but you can't use it if you want to test if child component's methods are called from parent.

Using ng-mocks library all you need to do is to swap

`declarations: [ TestedComponent, ChildComp]` in Daniel's answer for

`declarations: [ TestedComponent, MockComponent(ChildComp)]`

and the parent component can be tested without creating a hard dependency on a child component.